# 100% Height Div within Content Div

Tags: css, height

Here's my [Site](http://www.90slullaby.com/shoes-1/)

I'm trying to get the SubCategory bar's height to span through the entire content div.

I tried adding min-heigh: 100%, height:100%, to both the content div and the SubCategory div but no luck.

Right now the products are being floated right, which is a remedy to my issue, but for aesthetic purposes I would like them to float left as well but not cut under the SubCategory div.

Hope that made sense.

Comment: would you show us your code please?

Comment: Here is the content block  





.Content .Block {
clear: both;
}  


Here is the inner div SubCategory  



.SubCategoryList, .SubBrandList {
padding-top: 0px;
float: left;
}  



Sorry, I'm kinda new at all this. Let me know if you need anything else.  

I'm essentially trying to get the SubCategory Height to Equal the Content block height at all times.

Comment: `.Content, .Block { clear:both;} .SubCategory, .SubCategoryList, .SubBrandList { padding-top: 0px; float: left; }` make sure about the structure you're writing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the .SubCategoryList to be 100% the height of the .Content .Block parent element.

Add `position:relative` to `.Content .Block`. Then add `height:100%; position:absolute;` to `.SubCategoryList`.

Look something like this:

```
.Content .Block { clear:both; position:relative;}
.SubCategoryList { padding-top:0px; position:absolute; height:100%}
```

Hopefully, that gets you what you're after. You might also want to check out more information about the CSS `position` property at: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked like a charm. Would you mind explaining to me what exactly is the reasoning behind the postion rules? Just so I know why it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Sure. By declaring `position:relative` on the `.Content .Block` element, you are defining the `.SubCategoryList` element's containing element. Otherwise, it would be the first `position`ed ancestor as you travel back up the DOM...if none were found, it would default to the `html` element. The height of the contained element is then set to the height of the container element using `height:100%`.

Comment: btw, if it works out...feel free to mark this as the answer to your question. ;)